# Kalman filter for harmonic oscillator. State variable and Covariance matrix

Tags: kalman-filters, state

I've coded a simple damped harmonic oscillator, controlled with a pid. Works fine.

I want to use this model to test a kalman filter. So i added a gaussian noise to the position and want to feed the noisy position to a kalman filter but im a little lost regarding state variable and how to choose them and also the different matrix.

Here how far i got. Starting with the equation representing my system is:

$m \ddot x = -k*x -damp*\dot x + F$

I set the state variable as: $ \left( \begin{array}
  &x \\
  \dot x \\
   \ddot x \end{array}\right)$

the state model matrice as :$A= \left[ \begin{array}
  &1&dt& \frac{dt^2}{2} \\
  0&1&dt \\
   -\frac{k}{m}&-\frac{damp}{m}&1 \end{array}\right]$

the input model matrice as :$B= \left[ \begin{array}
  &0 \\
  0 \\
   1 \end{array}\right]$ and the input as: $u= \frac{F}{m}$

which gives the state estimate: $$x_{k+1} = A \cdot x_k + B\cdot u$$ and the covariance estimate:
$$ P_{k+1} = A\cdot P_k \cdot A^T + Q$$
where $P_0 =\left[ \begin{array}
  &100&0&0 \\
  0&100&0 \\
   0&0&100 \end{array}\right] $ ie we dont know where we are (as P=0 mean we are sure of our initial state from the wikipedia example)

I've set the observation $H=\left[ \begin{array}  &1&0&0\end{array}\right]$ bc we only look at the position and $Z =  \left( \begin{array}
  &x_n \\
  0  \\
   0  \end{array}\right)$ where $x_n$ is the position with the added noise.

the correction step being:

$K = P \cdot H^T \cdot \left( H \cdot P \cdot H^T +R\right)^{-1}$

$X_{k+1} = x_{k+1 estimate} + K\cdot (Z-H \cdot x_{k+1 estimate} ) $

$P_{k+1} = (I - K \cdot H)\cdot P_{k+1 estimate}$

So my two question are:

1. So far, are my differents matrices correct ? Also, any tip on how to choose the different state variable is welcome. Some model just position and velocity, some other position, velocity and acceleration some with the jerk and so on and i'm a little confuse.
2. I missed the covariance matrices Q and R. Right now they are set a $\sigma \cdot I$ with sigma a small value but i feel it's not right.

Thanks for your help !

EDIT:
I eventually find what seem to be the error.

The state model matrice should be: $A= \left[ \begin{array}
  &1&dt& \frac{dt^2}{2} \\
  0&1&dt \\
   -\frac{k}{m}&-\frac{damp}{m}& 0 \end{array}\right]$

The last term should be a $0$. If set at $1$ like before, it means that i'm adding the previous acceleration on top of the rest of the formula.

It's not the usual upper triangular matrix but it works none the less.

There still some pb as the filter position tend to be closer to the command than the real position so the pid stop acting which lead to a drift which is then violently compensated.
Also integrating the acceleration as a measurement lead, after a good beginning, to an oscillation explosion (it start to oscillate with bigger and bigger amaplitude). Decreasing the level of noise on the acceleration resolve the problem (still have some spike here and there) but if dont think it's the good solution.

Comment: You only want to do a prediction step and no correction step? Also your $A$ matrix looks wrong.

Comment: @fibonatic I just didn't add the correction part out of laziness and because i feel  my problem is more in the different matrices rather than the algorithm by itself